# Python telethon Как можно изменить ссылку собственного канала,

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Как можно изменить ссылку собственного канала или другую либо информацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon import sync, TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetChannelsRequest,  CheckUsernameRequest, UpdateUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel, InputPeerChannel
from config import *

client = TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH)
with client:
    cur_chan_username = '*********'
    response = client(ResolveUsernameRequest(cur_chan_username))

    createdPrivateChannel = GetChannelsRequest(InputChannel(cur_chan_username, response.chats[0].access_hash))


    newChannelID = response.chats[0].id
    newChannelAccessHash = response.chats[0].access_hash

    desiredPublicUsername = "new chan username"
    checkUsernameResult = client(
        CheckUsernameRequest(InputPeerChannel(channel_id=newChannelID, access_hash=newChannelAccessHash),
                             desiredPublicUsername))

    if (checkUsernameResult == True):
        publicChannel = client(
            UpdateUsernameRequest(InputPeerChannel(channel_id=newChannelID, access_hash=newChannelAccessHash),
                                  desiredPublicUsername))
```